# How to find out, where a library is defined in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Suppose `IntelliJ` says that my project uses some version of the library, like this:

[image]

How to find out where classes from this JAR are actually referenced?

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be a way to display dependency tree as you can with maven. 
You can run Gradle `dependencies` task to see the dependencies. To do it in Idea you can configure a `Gradle Run` configuration with task `dependencies`:

[image]